# Error ext-all-dev.js:12300 Error: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Tags: extjs, extjs4, extjs4.2

I have an application in ExtJS works perfectly but when creating the view sends me the following error:

Error: Can not read property 'length' of undefined ext-all-dev.js: 12300

procude the error in this line of code from the ext-all-dev.js (I used pause on uncaught exception in chrome):

```
getRenderTree: function() {
         var me = this, 
             result = me.callParent(arguments) 
             i, len; 

         for (i = 0, len = result.length; i <len; i + +) {
             result [i] = me.transformItemRenderTree (result [i]); 
         } 
         return result; 
     }
```

I created three classes:

1 - the name is Ext.ux.PanelFooter and extending 'Ext.panel.Panel'

2 - The name is Ext.ux.PanelHeader and extending 'Ext.panel.Panel'

3 - The name is Ext.ux.Toolbar and extends Ext.toolbar.Toolbar

Help please, thank you.

EDIT / UPDATE:

this is the code

```
var panelCenter = new Ext.panel.Panel({
        region: 'center',
        id: 'centerPanel',
        title: 'System Admin',
        enableTabScroll: true,
        border: true,
        layout: 'fit',      
        bodyPadding: '0 0 20 20',
        layout:'column',
        items: [{
            columnWidth: 1,
            layout:'column',
            frame: false,
            border: false,
            items: [{
                columnWidth: .25,
                html: '&nbsp;',
                frame: false,
                border: false
            },{
                title: 'Welcome',
                columnWidth: .5,
                height: 200,
                style: 'padding: 10px;',
                align: 'right',
                items: [{
                        xtype: 'panel',
                        layout: 'column',
                        frame: false,
                        border: false,
                        style: 'padding: 3px;',
                        items: [{
                            columnWidth: 1,
                            layout: 'form',
                            frame: false,
                            border: false,
                        }]
                    }]
            }]
        }]
    });
```

Answer (score 1):

I see - comma is missing in declaration:

`var me = this, 
          result = me.callParent(arguments) 
          i, len;`

So, the `result` gets undefined.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is accessed before it is rendered, however, it is too little info to be more specific.

Can you post some code or, even better, a showcase at http://fiddle.sencha.com please?